# Can I calculate the rotateY angle?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have to do this

[image]

So, can I calculate the rotateY angle in some way or this angle I can
define ONLY by eye estimate?

For example, I can do something like this by code below. But as you can see, this is not exactly what I want to do.

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(50deg);
  background: #efd9b5;
  border: 1px solid #b95656;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you would like to achieve? Also could you share an example code snippet of what you've tried already?

Comment: it's perspective combined with rotate and there is a lof of combination to obtain the same result

Comment: you may have some headaches but if you follow the duplicate carefully you will get all the formulas you want

Comment: @Temani Afif I have another question. You've read that D is width without transformation. How can I get it from this photo without rotate angle?

Comment: you can consider that your element is a square so the D will be the height of the left side. You don't really need to know all the variables because you can get the picture using a lot of combination. You can fix some of them and find the others

Comment: @Temani Afif Sorry for this stupid question, but look.
I tried to check how your formula works.
For example, in your answer in the first case you establish values like these
p - 100px;
D - 200px;
angle - (-45deg);....

and formula is R = (p * cos(angle) * D)/(p - (sin(angle) * D))
So, let's calculate:
R=(100*cos45*200)/(100 - sin45*200)
By the way:....cos45 - 0.52; sin45 - 0.85;
.................
R=100*0.85*200/100 - 0.85*200=17000/100-170= 17000/-70= -242
I tried so many times but I've never got the right result.
(Right result is 58px)

I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: you are not getting the correct value for cos and sin ... cos(45deg) = sin(45deg) = 0.707. Pay attention to the calculator your are using, the angle is in degree not radian

Comment: @Temani Afif Okay, I need engineering calculator.
And I've just tried to calculate this formula with right values of sin and cos, but it's still not right......
R=100*0.707*200/100 - (0.707*200)=70.7*200/100-141= 14140/-41=-344...
It's still not right

Comment: R = (100 * 0.707 * 200) / (100 - (-0.707*200)) = 14140 / 241.4 = 58.57 .... the sign of the angle is also important, -45deg and +45deg will not give the same sinus

Comment: @Temani Afif I can't figure out. Where did you get this minus? I looked everywhere and I didn't see this one. 
.......
For example -  http://math2.org/math/trig/tables.htm

Comment: why are you using tables? use a calculator: https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Sin_Calculator.html  .. sin(-45deg) = -0.707

Comment: @Temani Afif As I understand, sin angle ALWAYS will be with negative sign? Because it's the only way it works.

Comment: @Temani Afif And does it formula work only with rotateY? I mean, can I calculate the same with rotateX angle?

Comment: it's all about math an geometry, you need to find the right formula. You can do it for any transformation but you need to have a good background of math and understand how transform works in order to identify the formula. The formula I made works **only** for the above case. If you change something then you need a new formula

Comment: @Temani Afif Yeah, I need to rethink both my math and geometry:)
But I really appreciate your help. Thank you